# Hyper v on Windows Server 2012 and self service

Tags: team-foundation-server, hyper-v-server-2012

I cannot seem to find a concrete yes or no as to whether self-service is available still on Windows Server 2012 with Hyper V. I am wondering if it is still available for TFS Lab Management. Does Hyper V on Windows Server 2012 support self service AND is it usable within TFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "Self Service" but if you're looking for the Self-Service Portal that used to come with System Center Virtual Machine Manager, it has been split into a separate product called System Center App Controller.

There is not (and never was) self-service functionality built into the tools that ship with Windows Server itself (Cluster Manager and Hyper-V Manager).

Comment: What I am referring to is currently we have Win2k8R2 running Hyper V. It has a self service portal that can allow authorized users to create VMs without the need for an admin to get involved. In TFS 2010 you can use lab management (which we are starting to look at using) to provision test machines for QA. Our network admin is moving the Hyper V to Windows Server 2012 and am wondering if the self-service aspect is still available in Windows Server 2012 (System Center as you pointed out) AND if so is self service still an option for Lab Management.

Comment: @MikeCheel what you are describing is not a function of Hyper-V, but is a function of System Center Virtual Machine Manager and App Controller, as I've answered above. There has been no regression in functionality between 2010 and 2012 or 2012 R2 in this area.

Comment: Thank you very much. There has been some contention that it has gone away.

Comment: @MikeCheel I believe [this - the Virtual Machine Manager Self-Service Portal - is the feature you're referring to](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb740919.aspx), for future reference.

Comment: The VMM self service portal **did** go away. I spelled this out in my answer. It is now System Center App Controller. Same functionality, different name.